# CSS Animation is creating the animation effect in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, animation

I have a simple CSS Animation code but the animation effect is not shown in the Google Chrome browser.

I am not able to figure out what is missing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>CSS Animation</title>
    <style>
    @keyframes colors {
        0% ( background-color: red; )
        20% ( background-color: orange; )
        40% ( background-color: yellow; )
        60% ( background-color: green; )
        80% ( background-color: blue; )
        100% ( background-color: purple; )
    }
    #magic {
        width: 100px;
        padding: 1em;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 5em;
        border: 2px solid red;
        border-radius: 6px;
        animation-name: colors;
        animation-duration: 5s;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-direction: alternate;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="magic">Magic!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oqg94k6d/)**

Comment: It's not even working on firefox.

Comment: Your keyframes syntax is wrong. The braces should curly (`{`, `}`) and not round (`(`, `)`).

Comment: @Harry Noted, thanks. Tbh, I don't know how to create a stack snippet yet. Learning on it now.

Comment: @choz: It is very similar to fiddle. Just click on the `<>` icon in the toolbar to open the snippet window and then add the HTML, CSS, JS code in the appropriate boxes :)

Comment: @Harry WOw, that's actually ez.. Never noticed that button exists. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to **add** the `@-webkit-keyframes` syntax to support Chrome, Safari and Opera as well like so:

```
@-webkit-keyframes colors {
  0% { background-color: red;
  } 20% { background-color: orange;
  } 40% { background-color: yellow;
  } 60% { background-color: green;
  } 80% { background-color: blue;
  } 100% { background-color: purple;
  }
}
```

Also notice that you should be using curly braces instead of `(` and `)`

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rceaqg3q/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use @-webkit-keyframes for Chrome & Safari, @-moz-keyframes for Firefox, and @-o-keyframes for Opera.

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp